# Python - iterating through a list of integers

Tags: python, loops, integer

I have a dictionary containing keys that have values containing values such as "13896615011", "330405011", and some can contain multiple value like so: (3012292011, 1292123011)

I am running through a list of possible keys, where i say:

```
for x in list: 
   if (x in dict):
      found_match = dict.get(x)
      print(found_match)
```

And this gives me these values:

[13896615011]

[330405011]

[3012292011, 1292123011]

[2476681011]

[172450, 3109930011]

and so on.

Now, I have another dictionary that uses the values printed out above as keys, but when I use a for loop to read through each value, it gives me each integer separately like so:

```
for value in found_match:
   print(value)
```

And it would return, for the first value,

1

3

8

9

and so on, for all values in the list. The reason I want to iterate through found_match is because there can be two values and not just one. I want to append all the possible values returned from my second dictionary that uses the values (e.g 13896615011) as keys- so I can map the values to my first dictionary's original key.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you should append this   "  found_match "

Comment: I'm confused as to the types of the values in your dictionary. Are they strings and tuples of integers? Or strings and tuples of strings? Or lists? From the way the program behaves when you iterate through "found_match" it seems like they're strings when they're single values at least, and you're iterating over characters rather than integers.

Comment: A little nitpick: don't call your objects by the name of Python types `(list, dict).`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want

```
found_match=[]
for x in list: 
   if (x in dict):
      found_match.append(dict.get(x))
      print(found_match)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would really help if you could post a functioning block of code to replicate the issue. But, It sounds like you're having problems with object types, ie your for loop that is printing individual characters is doing so because `found_match` is a string.

Some pointers I can give based on what I understand in your question is this:

```
for x in _list:
   if x in _dict:
      print(_dict[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your overwriting the variable `found_match` with each iteration of your for loop

What you want is probabily the following:

```
matches = []

for x in list: 
    if (x in dict):
        found_match = dict.get(x)

        matches.append(found_match)
        print(found_match)


for value in matches:
    print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

(Implying you intentions from the above answers)

This sounds like a good example for list comprehension

```
matches = [dict.get(x, 0) for x in _list if x in list(dict.keys())]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want the dictionary ,values to be read as list.What you can do is store the values in a list instead of a single variable:

```
Values = []
    for x in list:
        if (x in dict):
            Values.extend( dict.get(x) )        

for x in list(Values):
   print(x)
```

Comment: This might have problems when the value of the dictionary is a tuple or list, since appending the value to Values will append the entire object. Maybe the value should be cased by type, and "extend" rather than "append" should be used if the value is a tuple or list

Comment: If this is a dictionary,where are the keys?